# How to set custom rewrite in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, url-rewrite

I am moving Magento 2.2.7 to new version 2.3.2. Theme migration has just finished, but some urls not working. e.g In original site https://www.magento.com/media indicated to pub/media, but in my local, it doesn't indicate and shows 404 error. And base url is "http://127.0.0.1/magento", but some links redirect to http://127.0.0.1/suburl, not http://127.0.0.1/magento/suburl. Who can solve this problem?